# Why does `window.console.log(this)` not log the console object?

Tags: javascript, oop, javascript-objects, prototypal-inheritance

I'm just getting into advanced contextual instantiation, using prototype chain etc.

I'm curious how the `window.console` object is created such that the function `log` thinks it's context is the window instance, not the console. Is this something to do with `Object.create` the `new` keyword, or binding / self = this?

`window.console` has a constructor (Console) and I'm curious what the cleanest way to invoke the constructor, passing Window instance/context would be? Pass it in as a param?? If Console is a seperate constructor, I think Window would be the one constructing it with a new context, rather than saying

```
windowInstance.console.log = function (args) {

}.bind(windowInstance, args);
```

Pretty much, I'm imagining a layout like this, but don't understand how `this` gets routed

```
var window = new Window();
window.console.log(this); // logs window

function Window () {
    // this === window when constructed above
    this.console = new Console();
}

function Console () {
    this.log = function () {} // where this === window.console but log thinks it's window
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your code logs nothing: http://jsfiddle.net/nn3dq1L6/ It's not obvious what "but log thinks it's window" is based on.

Comment: Its that way for everything, not just `console.log`.  I could be wrong, but as far as I can tell, the scope of `this` matters during execution; if it were executed from within a function, it'd have the parent as `this`, however, you're executing it in the scope of the window.

Comment: You're passing `this` into the function. That'll log the value of `this` as it is **outside** of the `console.log()` function, not the value of `this` inside.

Comment: @Pointy I tried to say that, but my wording is unfortunately not as efficient as yours :/

Comment: @Daedalus ha ha, no I saw your comment after mine was typed in and I agree you're saying the same thing.

Comment: sorry guys...... brain lapse

Answer (score 5):

If you had:

```
var obj = { hello: "world" };
console.log(obj);
```

would you be surprised that the console showed that object?  Well by the same token,

```
console.log(this);
```

logs the value of `this` as it is **outside** the call to the console function. You can't force `console.log()` to log what it thinks the value of `this` is in its own frame of reference; there's just no provision for that in the API (because frankly it's not very useful). If you want to log the state of the `window.console` object however you can:

```
console.log(window.console);
```